# How to create an `<a>` link if something is true?

Tags: angularjs

I know this question sounds redundant but I'm learning angular and would it be possible to create a link if a condition met is true or would I just have to do all the work on the front end?

```js
  $scope.no_animal_number = function('animalnumber'){
      var noassignednumber;    
      if(noassignednumber == ''){
        noassignednumber = "{{ l.animaltype }}";
      }if(nocode == 'animalnumber')
        nocode = "<a href="site.php?site={{ l.animalnumber }}">{{ l.animaltype }}</a>";
    }
return noassignednumber;
}
```

```html
 <tr ng-repeat="l in animal_list">
    <td>{{ l.animalnumber }}</td>
    <td>{{ no_animal_number(l.animaltype) }}</td>
 </tr>
```

this was my attempt at creating a function to do this.

Comment: It's better to create the link in markup and then control whether it is shown or not using a variable. You should avoid DOM manipulation (even something as simple as creating a hyperlink) in the controller as it is a bad design pattern for Angular.

Comment: so to manipulate the data would I use an ng-if statement to make not show a link if there was no animal number listed but there was other information on the table? Then in the controller pull animalnumber from the sql table?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, yes. Build the hyperlink in the view and then condition its display using `ng-if` or `ng-show`.

Comment: I found this as an example https://embed.plnkr.co/yhUnz8g0BOm50x4nNopZ/ but how would I make the controller part dynamic to where it reads the animal number when the table is updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing because you are calling a function from your view, but the way you have created that function on your controller doesn't look like it would work.

Here is what I would recommend (or something similar based on your specific needs):

```
<tr ng-repeat="l in animal_list">
    <td>{{l.animalnumber}}</td>
    <td>
        <span ng-if="l.animalnumber">{{l.animaltype}}</span>
        <span ng-if="!l.animalnumber">
            <a href="site.php?site={{l.animaltype}}">{{l.animaltype}}</a>
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Yeah I think I might've asked it improperly. What I mean is if the user chooses to update that table row to an animalnumber and updates it to 123 then instead of it showing just a static name Mary(Husky) it shows a link to information about the animal, and in that example the plunker shows he created a function but it's hard coded in.

Comment: `ng-if` is a bit heavy to render, I would recommand `ng-show`

Comment: You may also need to treat the case when `l.animalnumber === 0`

Comment: thank you for the help! ^_^ I was wondering why it didn't work when I plugged it in and then I saw that I had a syntax error. :)